# Is it possible to apply for a long-stay visa in Belgium while you are there on short-stay?

Tags: visa, us-citizens, belgium

I'm a Belgian citizen. My American girlfriend comes to visit me for three months at a time but the plan is for her to eventually stay here permanently. When the time comes that she meets the requirements for a cohabitation visa, can she request the necessary documents/procedures and submit the visa application here during her visit?

I ask simply because it seems like an unnecessary annoyance for her to have to travel to a different state to visit a Belgian consulate in the US in person when she's legally staying here for extended periods of time anyway.

Comment: Germany and the Netherlands, at least allow citizens of certain countries, including the US, to do this. Belgium might, too, but I don't know.

Comment: @phoog That is hopeful at least. I silly for having to ask this question as a Belgian citizen myself but the government websites are a mess and government hard to reach.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Expatica](https://www.expatica.com/be/visas-and-permits/Moving-to-Belgium-Guide-to-Belgian-visas-and-permits_100069.html#LongTermVisa):

> If you’re already in Belgium – perhaps because you don't need an entry visa for less than three months, or you have a residence card for another purpose – you should apply at the [local Belgian municipal administration offices/](http://www.belgium.be/fr/adresses_et_sites/overview.jsp?f=YXV0aG9yaXR5TGV2ZWw9L1ZpbGxlcyBldCBjb21tdW5lcw==&s=)town hall (maison communale/gemeentehuis).
>
> You’ll need to complete an [application form for a long-stay visa in Belgium](https://dofi.ibz.be/sites/dvzoe/EN/Documents/Application_for_a_visa_for_a_long_stay_in_Belgium.pdf), and also supply originals and copies of other documents, which may include:
>
> - a valid passport/travel ID document;
> - a work permit, proof of registration at an educational institution, marriage/civil partnership or birth certificates (if applicable);
> - proof that you can support yourself during your stay;
>     proof of accommodation;
> - a medical certificate to prove that you don’t have any disease which could endanger public health;
> - a certificate to show you don’t have a criminal record.
>
> The visa takes the form of a sticker in your passport/travel ID.

The information, in English, references [Agentschap Integratie & Inburgering](http://www.agii.be/).